# Using Source Link to download source from local .snupkg for debugging

Tags: c#, nuget, sourcelink

My understanding is that Visual Studio debugging doesn't support extracting sources from an embedded PDB.  I've read that Source Link can use a local NuGet repo to download the source for debugging.  I've created .nupkg and .snupkg of a test library, using this in the csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
  <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
  <EmbedAllSources>true</EmbedAllSources>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I think I need to use Source Link to pull the source code from the .snupkg.  However, all I can find in the documentation is how to download the source from online (GitHub, etc.).  Is this possible?

Comment: Personally i just use JetBrains [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). it dissembles everything

Comment: See following : https://www.wintellect.com/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know/